# HTTP Request Sampler not working

Tags: jmeter

I am using windows7 and the latest version of Jmeter. I created a simple HTTP Request Sampler and in the server name I added google.com

When I ran it I got the following error:

```
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/11/30 14:15:32 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/11/30 14:15:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/11/30 14:15:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/11/30 14:15:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/11/30 14:15:33 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal output of JMeter, it indicates that JMeter started and finished one thread one time.

You can visualize test  results with [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), in particular [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) is extremely useful for test script development and debugging.

As you can see at below image:

- the request is successful (green triangle)
- google search page is displayed at "Response data" tab
- log viewer contains the same entries as you posted

Don't forget to disable listeners for the actual test execution, they consume a lot of resources. You'll be able to open results file after test run using "Browse" button and perform analysis.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for detailed information on getting to the bottom of JMeter test script problem.